# Get AWS EC2 Spot instance launch time from within the instance itself in python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm running a big fleet of EC2 spot instances. I need to know the current instance age (since launch time) from within each instance, using Python.
I'm using boto3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determining Amazon EC2 instance creation date/time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18916135/determining-amazon-ec2-instance-creation-date-time)

Comment: Thanks Mark, but my problem is to achieve that from within the instance itself and using boto3

Comment: In that case, look at this: https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Instance.launch_time This is really simple to figure out if you just look at the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "within the EC2 instance", I assume you want to execute the python code on EC2 instance. Once you've working AWS python code, it doesn't matter on which computer/machine you run, it will work as long as system meets python and network requirements.

If you're looking for `launch_time`, you can use the following code.

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='instance_region_name')
instance = ec2.Instance('instance_id')
print instance.launch_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

If you're looking for instance's creation time, Please refer my answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38621178/6632342)

**Please Note that creation time and launch time both are different. You can launch the given instance as many times as you want, but creation happens only once**