# How to check the aws ec2 instance creation date using command line?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

To determine how old the aws ec2 instances are, and to destroy those nodes if they are older than 90 days, I need to check the creation date of the node.

What is the correct way to do that using COMMAND LINE?

What I tried?

I tried the command `ec2metadata`, but the output doesn't contain creation date.

Comment: What command line?  Bash, Powershell, CICS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determining Amazon EC2 instance creation date/time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18916135/determining-amazon-ec2-instance-creation-date-time)

Comment: No @Paolo. My question specifically asks about the "using command line only". The answers in the above question include python scripts, which I don't want.

Answer (score 2):

You can get this information with

```
aws configservice get-resource-config-history --resource-type AWS::EC2::Instance --resource-id i-xxxxxxxx
```

The last element in this json is what you need.
You can check [get-resource-config-history](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/configservice/get-resource-config-history.html) and find resources between specific dates.
You can also get creation date of your root volume with

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes --volume-ids vol-xxxxx
```

This can also give you age of your root volume (if not changed).